# How to call something in Bash with an arbitray number of arguments without eval and string concatenation

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script that calls a command, which returns a table, and I need to use that information to call a second command as arguments. Is it possible to do it without string concatenation and eval?

Example 1

```
$ command1 inputfile
1:    1    2    3
2:    6   10   20
$ command2 -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 file1 -a 6 -b 10 -c 20 file2
```

Example 2

```
$ command1 inputfile
1:    1    2    3
2:    6   10   20
3:    7    8    4
$ command2 -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 file1 -a 6 -b 10 -c 20 file2 -a 7 -b 8 -c 4 file3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

[Parameter Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

[Process Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()
while read filenum parm1 parm2 parm3
do
  args+=(-a "$parm1" -b "$parm2" -c "$parm3" "file${filenum%:}")
done < <(command1 inputfile)
command2 "$args[@]"
```